# Leonovo Ideapad 720S-13ARR display flickering

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, lenovo-laptop, display-driver

So I have a Lenovo Ideapad 720S-13ARR and the display is flickering. See the video here: https://streamable.com/14qji6

The first few seconds of flickering in the video is actually the display getting very dark. When I change the display brightness again it *actually* starts flickering.

So I have googled around and there are [some](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-IdeaPad-1xx-3xx-5xx-7xx-Edge-LaVie-Z-Flex-Notebooks/Flashing-screen-Lenovo-Ideadpad-720S-13ARR-notebook/m-p/4626524?page=1#4626524) [threads](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-IdeaPad-1xx-3xx-5xx-7xx-Edge-LaVie-Z-Flex-Notebooks/ideapad-720S13ARR-Screen-Flicking-Problem/m-p/4253136?page=1#4253398) that say that a driver update of the AMD Vega 8 graphics unit is responsible for this. Therefore I tried to get rid of that driver by uninstalling it entirely, however, to no avail. Without any AMD graphics driver (i.e. with the basic windows display driver) I still have the same issue. Even when entering only the BIOS, the display is very dark and/or flickers.

I still don't want to believe that this is a hardware issue. Any other ideas?

Comment: Start with a bootable USB Key, If still flickering, it is a hardware error (backlight or possibly display). You said same for BIOS, so almost for sure it is a hardware issue.

Comment: Can you point me to a quick tutorial to create a bootable USB key? Thanks!

Comment: Use a Windows 10 ISO and make a bootable key from it (Microsoft Media Creation Link).

Comment: But isnt the fact that the same thing appears in the BIOS already confirmation that it is a hardware issue?

Comment: Yes. it is a hardware problem.

Answer (score 1):

A flickering and darkening display as described is a hardware issue. The same flickering and darkening occurs in BIOS and in the Operating system. BIOS is very basic and so a display hardware here that is the same as in the OS is a hardware problem.

Problems:  Backlight gone bad, cable seating or issue, and possibly the display as well.

Solution:  Get the laptop serviced and have the defective parts replaced.